# to generate a serial number column for the duplicated values of one column in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How do I create a column `dup_duns_number` having the index number for the duplicated values increasing by 1.

```
    DUNS_NUMBER  dup_DUNS_NUMBER
0             0              1.0
1             0              1.0
2             0              1.0
3             0              1.0
4       1000231              NaN
5       1000236              NaN
6       1000363              2.0
7       1000363              2.0
8       1000368              NaN
9       1000467              NaN
10      1000470              3.0
11      1000470              3.0
12      1000470              3.0
13      1000553              4.0
14      1000553              4.0
15      1000574              NaN
16      1000657              5.0
17      1000657              5.0
18      1000694              NaN
19      1000744              6.0
20      1000744              6.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you do it in two steps: first you have to filter the duplicated values and *rank* them to give you the increasing index number and then union the non-duplicated values, like so:

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, count, lit, dense_rank 

df = spark.createDataFrame([(0,), (0,), (0,), (0,), (1000231,), (1000236,), (1000363,), (1000363,)], "DUNS_NUMBER: int")

count_window = Window.partitionBy("DUNS_NUMBER")
order_window = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("DUNS_NUMBER")

df_with_count = df.withColumn("dup_COUNT", count(col("DUNS_NUMBER")).over(count_window))

df_with_count \
    .filter("dup_COUNT > 1") \
    .withColumn("dup_DUNS_NUMBER", dense_rank().over(order_window)) \
    .union( \
        df_with_count.filter("dup_COUNT = 1").withColumn("dup_DUNS_NUMBER", lit("NaN"))) \
    .select(["DUNS_NUMBER", "dup_DUNS_NUMBER"]) \
    .orderBy("DUNS_NUMBER") \
    .show()

+-----------+---------------+
|DUNS_NUMBER|dup_DUNS_NUMBER|
+-----------+---------------+
|          0|              1|
|          0|              1|
|          0|              1|
|          0|              1|
|    1000231|            NaN|
|    1000236|            NaN|
|    1000363|              2|
|    1000363|              2|
+-----------+---------------+
```